# Combine 2 SQL Query results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-date-functions

I want to combine my 2 sql results and 1 more filter which is Date.
How Can I combine my these 2 sql queries.

First sql

```
 SELECT e.Name,COUNT(l.userName) as UsersVisit
  FROM Table1 l
  INNER JOIN Table2 e on e.UserName =l.UserName
  WHERE 
  ( l.DateAccessed>'3-31-2015' and l.DateAccessed <'4-30-2015')
  Group by e.Name
```

O/P I get

```
Name  UsersVisit
abc    10
xyz    20
def    30
```

Second Sql

```
SELECT COUNT(1) as TotalVisits
  FROM Table1 l
  INNER JOIN Table2 e on e.UserName =l.UserName
  WHERE 
  ( l.DateAccessed>'3-31-2015' and l.DateAccessed <'4-30-2015')
  ORDER BY TotalVisits DESC
```

O/P I get

```
TotalVisits
60
```

Now, the O/P I want is

```
UniqueUsers  TotalVisits  Month
3               60        March
4               50        April
```

3 is the unique number of users(abc,xyz,def), while TotalVisits is the count of all the UsersVisit

How can I get these result ?

Comment: `group by usersvisit, month`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine your select clause and use the datename and datepart functions

```
select dateName(month, DateAccessed) "Month"
, datePart(month, DateAccessed) sortColumn
, count(1) totalVisits
, count(distinct l.userName) UsersVisit
from and where clause goes here
group by dateName(monthDateAccessed)
order by sortColumn
```

In your display code, don't display the sort column.  Also, if your search period is more than a year, you may want to incorporate the year into the equation.

Comment: The error i get is **DateAccessed' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.**